# Remove AzureAD user from all groups -powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I've been trying to remove all of the groups(M365,DL,security etc.) from a user.
I was trying to use this script but I'm getting errors when removing DLs(reasonably).

```
$Groups = Get-AzureADUserMembership  -ObjectId $userID 
foreach($Group in $Groups.ObjectId){
Remove-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $Group -MemberId $userID 
}
```

My problem is that I have no way to get the type of the group and treat it with the correct command accordingly. When trying to use MSOL to get the type I saw that M365 groups are also being shown as a distribution list, So I'm not able to use this method.

Any advice or luck with that?
Thanks!

Edit:
This is how the groups are showing up, identical but not actually as it requires different command to remove the group.
[365 group and DL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjIx0.png)

Comment: "I have no way to get the type of the group" - really? Can't you call `Get-AzureADObjectByObjectId $Group` and inspect the object it returns? :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Gives me the same results as if I use Get-AzureADGroup but my problem is not that.
My problem is that when using PowerShell, M365 group and DL are looking exactly the same as you can see in the picture I've edited on my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that Azure AD group memberships can be removed via `Remove-AzureAdGroupMember` while Exchange Online memberships via `Remove-DistributionGroupMember`, executing both commands via a `try..catch` is probably the most efficient way to meet the OP's requirements.
The code below does just that (remove the comment before the `Confirm` parameter to skip confirmation.)

```
Connect-AzureAD
Connect-ExchangeOnline

$userid = (Get-AzureADuser -objectid "test.user@testdomain.test").objectid

$Groups = Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $userID 
foreach($Group in $Groups){ 
    try { 
        Remove-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $Group.ObjectID -MemberId $userID -erroraction Stop 
    }
    catch {
        write-host "$($Group.displayname) membership cannot be removed via Azure cmdlets."
        Remove-DistributionGroupMember -identity $group.mail -member $userid -BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck # -Confirm:$false
    }
}
```

Note: proper code formatting *does* help.

Comment: Thanks!
I guess this will be the closest to a "clean" run on the script. Still getting the errors on the screen but that fine I guess as its doing its job.

Answer (score 0):

***I have tried with same script in my environment to remove an user from the groups and it removed successfully .***

***Azure portal->Groups->Enter your Group name***

In my Azure Active directory ,I have Microsoft group type with 5 users:

[image]

[image]

In my Security Group type I have 4 users:

[image]

[image]
I tried with particular user like ***imran khan*** to remove from these two groups.
[image]

First you need to connect with azureAD using this command :

```
Import-Module AzureAD
$Credential = Get-Credential
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential
```

Now I tried with same commands:

```
$userID = 'user object ID'
$Groups = Get-AzureADUserMembership  -ObjectId $userID 
foreach($Group in $Groups.ObjectId){
Remove-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $Group -MemberId $userID 
}
```

[image]

***Response:***
[image]

Which returned empty that means which I removed successfully a user from the group.

***Reference:***
[Compare groups - Microsoft 365 admin | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/create-groups/compare-groups?view=o365-worldwide)

Comment: Removing M365 group and security are working just fine, my issue start when trying to remove distribution groups from a user.
I have no way of knowing by powershell if a group is M365 or DL, which means i'm not using the correct command for the specific group type.

Remove-AzureADGroupMember for M365 and all the other group types
and
Remove-DistributionGroupMember for distribution list